Long Term Car Storage of a normal car
If you were to store a car in covered parking for 6-months to 1-year or more at a time, what would you do to keep in a reliable shape?
To my limited knowledge, here are somethings that came to mind:

Keep the battery charged with a battery tender.
Add fuel stabilizer to stop the gasoline from gelling.  Is this also true for diesel?
Prevent the tires from developing a flat-patch.  Can this be done by increasing the tire pressure just for storage?
Would a car cover help?
Disengaged the parking brake. Have experienced brake disc warping multiple times during storage in as little as a couple of weeks.
This one is extreme, but I've heard of nitrogen filled garages.

To clarify, this would not be a vintage or high-value car.  It'd be just a car you keep instead of renting for a month when you visit the same place once or twice a year.

Diesel is not mentioned in the question at the duplicate link, so note that diesel fuel is stable long-term if it does not have water in the tank. Best to fill the tank full to discourage the tank "breathing" with temperature changes, which slowly causes water to accumulate. I keep extra diesel fuel in sealed 15 gallon drums and use them for a fill-up when they reach 10 years old. VW TDI, Dodge Cummins truck and Yanmar generator run on it with no issues. If your vehicle gives  frequent water in fuel warnings, use a biocide diesel additive before storing vehicle to prevent growth of slime.
